# If Class exists && If Method exists PHP / Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, abstract

PHP/Laravel

Hey, I'm moving into abstraction in php and am attempting to validate and store values based on whatever has been submitted, where I expect that the methods should neither know what to validate against and/or which class and method to use to do so -

What I've got works but I can see that there would be issues where classes/methods do not exist. Here lays my question.

If I were to call a method in the following format, which way would be best to 'check' if `class_exists()` or the `method exists()`?

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $dataSet = $request->all();
    $inputs = $this->findTemplate();

    $errors = [];
    $inputValidators = [];
    foreach ($inputs as $input) {
        $attributes = json_decode($input->attributes);
        if (isset($attributes->validate)) {
            $inputValidators[$input->name] = $input->name;
        }
    }

    foreach ($dataSet as $dataKey => $data) {
        if (array_key_exists($dataKey, $inputValidators)) {
           $validate = "validate" . ucfirst($dataKey);
           $validated = $this->caseValidator::{$validate}($data);
            if ($validated == true) {
                $inputValidators[$dataKey] = $data;
            } else {
                $errors[$dataKey] = $data;
            }
        } else {
            $inputValidators[$dataKey] = $data;
        }
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        $this->mapCase($dataSet);
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->with(['errors' => $errors]);
    }
}
```

```
public function mapCase($dataSet)
{
    foreach($dataSet as $dataKey => $data) {
        $model = 'case' . ucfirst($dataKey);
        $method = 'new' . ucfirst($dataKey);
        $attribute = $this->{$model}::{$method}($dataKey);

        if($attribute == false) {
            return redirect()->back()->with(['issue' => 'error msg here']);
        }
    }
    return redirect()->back->with(['success' => 'success msg here'])'
}
```

For some additional context, an input form will consist of a set of inputs, this can be changed at any time. Therefore I am storing all values as a json 'payload'.

When a user submits said form firstly the active template is found, which provides details on what should be validated `$input->attributes`, once this has been defined I am able to call functions from `caseValidator` model as `$this->caseValidator::{$validate}($data);`.

I do not think that any checks for existence will be needed here as the validation parameters are defined against an input, thus if none exist this check will be skipped using `if (array_key_exists($dataKey, $inputValidators))`

However, I am dispersing some data to other tables within the second block of code using `mapCase()`. This is literally iterating over all array keys regardless of if a method for it exists and thus the initial check cannot be made as seen in the first block. I've attempted to make use of `class_exists()` and `method_exists` but logically it does not fit and I cannot expect them to work as I'd like, perhaps my approach in `mapCase` is not correct? I guess if I'm defining a class for each key I should instead use one class and have methods exist there, which would remove the need to check for the class existing. Please advise

Reference:

```
$attribute = $this->{$model}::{$method}($dataKey);
```

Comment: FYI, this code works just fine, but I know as soon as `mapCase()` is given an input which I've not setup a default for, it will error

Comment: Just want to confirm... you're accepting input from a user, and the users provides the list of validators to use?

Comment: in the `store()` method, I pickup `$dataSet` which is the literal value and 'name' of what they submitted, `$inputs` is then given the active form template `findTemplate()`. It is `$inputs` which now has all input criteria available. Validation is stored in a json payload field there, which is used if the 'name' of the input field submitted by the user is matched

Comment: Admin users can create inputs, defining validation and such, they can then define which inputs are in which template and which template is active. Said template will be displayed as a form for non-admin users @Populus

Comment: Can you store all your validators in a map, then use the key to access them? Each validator would implement a `Validator` interface with a `validate` method that returns `boolean`.

Comment: Basically I'm not a fan of your code not knowing if classes or methods exists. `class_exists()` and `method_exists()` are old school methods for when PHP was barely object oriented.

Comment: I'd still have to use 'if method exists' if I did that, considering I'm passing data that will run through that code, sometimes without this extra layer of validation, perhaps I should just create an available method array

Comment: For example, I require one specific input to be checked against an API response and the others are similar in terms of large code chunks, so I'd rather keep files separate, albeit I could just redirect methods from a validator - I'll attempt a different approach and drop it here if I think its more suitable. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the potential issue by using `class_exists()`, considering I know the method names as they are the same as the `$dataKey`.

```
    public function mapCase($dataSet)
    {
        foreach($dataSet as $dataKey => $data) {
            $model = 'case' . ucfirst($dataKey);
            if (class_exists("App\Models\CaseRepository\\" . $model)) {
                $method = 'new' . ucfirst($dataKey);
                $attribute = $this->{$model}::{$method}($dataKey);
            }

            if($attribute == false) {
                return redirect()->back()->with(['issue' => 'error msg here']);
            }
        }
        return redirect()->back->with(['success' => 'success msg here'])'
    }
```